# How to add localStorage to my multilanguage website

Tags: javascript, jquery

The translator works perfect. There are no bugs but whenever i refresh the browser or click the link, the page returns to it's original form.how to add localstorage in my code ? and thanks for help

```
    function change() {
    var i = document.getElementById("lan").value;
    if (i==1) {
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML ="عسلامة";
        document.getElementById("p").innerHTML="باي";
        document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "http://www.cnn.com/";
    } else if (i==2) {
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML ="welcome";
        document.getElementById("p").innerHTML="good bye";
        document.getElementById("myAnchor").href = "http://www.google.com/";  
    }
    localStorage.setItem("language",language);
}
    <select form="langform" id="lan" onchange="change()">
    <option value="1" selected>arabic</option>
    <option value="2">English</option>
</select>
  <h1 id="title">title 1</h1>
  <p id="p"> learn js</p>
  <a id="myAnchor" href="#">go to</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a dictionary object, where the keys are actually your desired element IDs
- Don't use inline JS, same as you hopefully don't use inline style attributes. JS should be in one place only, and that's your script tag or file. Use [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- Use `localStorage.language =` to store a desired value
- Use `= localStorage.language;` to read your value from LS.
- Be flexible, use a function for one job only, if it's for applying the language, name it so and use it where needed:

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1sL409xv/)

```js
const EL_lanSelect = document.querySelector("#lan")
let lan = localStorage.language || "ar"; // or fallback to a default ("ar")

EL_lanSelect.value = lan;
EL_lanSelect.addEventListener("change", changeLan);

const dict = {
  title: {ar: "عسلامة", en: "welcome"},
  p: {ar: "باي", en: "good bye"},
  myAnchor: {ar: "توجه", en: "Go to"},
};

const href = {
  myAnchor: {ar: "http://www.cnn.com/", en: "http://www.google.com/"},
};


function changeLan() {
  lan = EL_lanSelect.value;
  localStorage.language = lan;
  applyLan();
}

function applyLan() {
  Object.keys(dict).forEach( k => {
    document.getElementById(k).innerHTML = dict[k][lan];
  });
  Object.keys(href).forEach( k => {
    document.getElementById(k).setAttribute("href", href[k][lan]);
  });
}

// Init!
applyLan();
```

```html
<select form="langform" id="lan"> <!-- never use inline JS -->
  <option value="ar" selected>arabic</option>
  <option value="en">English</option>
</select>
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<p id="p"></p>
<a id="myAnchor" href="#"></a>
```

---

Comment: sorry just one question i want to hide href  just  show go to

Comment: @abdelkader added an example. The simplest is to use another dictionary, this time for your HREFs

Answer (score 0):

First thing would be to save the `lan` in the localStorage when the user change it. In your change function there should be:

```js
var i = document.getElementById("lan").value;
...
localStorage.setItem("lan", i);
```

The other thing to do is to select by default the saved language, and to trigger th change function to update the translations when the page first load.
That could be done using a script, for example at the to the bottom of the page:

```js
var lan = localStorage.getItem("lan") || 'ar'
document.querySelector('#lan [value="' + lan + '"]').selected = true;
```